# Can i have limit posts on a specific category and automatically remove older ones?

Tags: plugins, posts, categories

i need to limit the number of posts on a specific category and if a new post is created and placed this category, but the number of maximum posts is reached, then the older one automatically been removed from that category.

Is that something possible that can happen in a plugin? If so, anyone that can help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could achieve this by just setting the "Blog pages show at most" setting from the dashboard: Settings -> Reading options.

Alternatively, you could create a custom template for the specific category in question and then set the posts per page equal to however many posts you want to display and order by settings to descending from there. Which would automatically display the most recent most post at the top.